# I can't seem to get my background image to load, can someone tell me what might be wrong?

Tags: html, css, background, ejs

I also have it in my images folder. I have tried

```
background-image: url("./header.jpg");
background-image: url("../header.jpg");
background-image: url("../images/header.jpg");
background-image: url("./images/header.jpg");
background-image: url("header.jpg");
```

[This is my directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WaU2t.png)

Comment: Have you tried just `background-image: url("header.jpg");`? It looks like that file is in the same folder as your CSS.

Comment: No luck there either.

Comment: Do you have any error in the browser console? Something like a 404 error. Try to press `F12` key to open the developer console in a browser and reload the page, see the HTTP requests related to HTML/CSS code in the `network` section and show us if you're getting some error.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to keep things nice and tidy. Cut and paste the 'header.jpg' into your 'images' folder and then try this:

```
    background-image: url(../images/header.jpg);
```

You must include the image root folder because that is the folder the header.jpg is in.

Comment: So I just tried this and the image still isn't coming up

Comment: Ensure you are putting the 'header.jpg' into your 'images' folder, not your 'css' folder.

Answer (score 0):

Your path will change depending on what your file structure looks like.

If your file structure looks like this:

```
root
----
index.html
image1.jpg
```

Your file path in your HTML should look like this.

```
background-image: url("./image1.jpg");
```

If, however, your file structure looks like this:

```
root
----
index.html
images (folder)
 ->  image1.jpg
```

Your file path should look like this.

```
background-image: url("./images/image1.jpg");
```

If your images folder is up a level, like this:

```
root
----
views (folder)
  ->  index.html
images(folder)
  ->  image1.jpg
```

Then your file path should be

```
background-image: url("../images/image1.jpg");
```